# select and copy files with N lines

Tags: linux, bash, unix, wc

I would like to select and copy from a folder only the files with a number N of lines.

How it is possible to do this in Bash?

Al.

Comment: actually possible:) share us your tryings.

Comment: I probably need to restate  my question, isn't? I tried with "find" but it has no "number of lines options", apparently.

Comment: Use this: `find . -type f -exec wc -l {} \;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using a loop in bash:

```
for f in *; do
    [ -f "$f" ] && [ $(wc -l < "$f") = 8 ] && cp "$f" "$dest"
done
```

This will loop through all the files and folders in your directory. The first test checks the target is a file. The second checks that the number of lines is 8. If both are true, `cp` the file to `"$dest"`.

**edit**: If you wanted to include hidden files as well, you could change the loop to `for f in .* *`. Thanks @chepner for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: Add `.*` to the list of items to iterate over if you want hidden files as well.

Comment: @chepner thanks, I've added it as another possibility.